# XML file change attribute value without reading whole file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have developed automation application for an application where I read XML files perform test. Input files are really huge. Input XML contains an attribute BatchId. This attribute is in root element itself. I want to modify this attribute value to datetime.now after completion of my test. If I read the whole file it is going to hit the performance. As I am thinking of some performance test with same data.

Thanks,
Anup

Comment: Have you considered keeping a separate file that contains the names and datetime of the last time you accessed that file.  If you change an XML file attribute in place you have to use exactly the same number of characters originally in the attribute value or corrupt your XML.

Comment: Currently I am changing the attribute value manually since the automation is under development. I can use the same number of characters no problem with that my max limit is 38 char. I am fine using any unique number less than 38 digit. DateTime was just one way to get uniqueness any other simple and better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe method is to use XmlReader/XmlWriter to copy the XML, modifying it on the fly. This article is helpful: [Combining the XmlReader and XmlWriter classes for simple streaming transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx)

The quick and dangerous method is to ensure the original XML document has a placeholder timestamp that you can replace with a new timestamp (their sizes must be equal). Use an ordinary filestream (treating the file as a binary file) to locate the attribute's location (say, by loading the first few hundred bytes into memory and search for the attribute name) and replace it directly in the file using seek and write. Be *very* careful if you choose doing this. A different encoding or other changes you don't account for will give you a corrupted file unless you test everything.

Comment: Thanks Dag, I would first like to try with safe method. I created XMLReader XMLWriter and gave input file to both. I don't want to create another file. When I try to read and write simultaneously its throwing except that file is being used by another process.

Comment: Can I use XDocument instead of XMLReader XMLWriter. Which one will be faster and consume less memory?

Comment: You must read and write to different files. If the file wasn't locked, you could (theoretically) end up overwriting data you are about to read. Both XmlDocument and XDocument will read the entire document into memory. The reader/writer classes will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file that contains only the root element and its attributes, plus an entity reference to another file which contains the content of the root element. Then you only need to modify the small wrapper file. For this you will need to use an XML parser that doesn't expand entity references, or (probably simpler in this case) a non-XML approach.